# How can I change the button for all active clients when clicked?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want to create something that can either be active or inactive. The button shows the state the application is in. At first, the button is green and the text says 'Start'. So when someone clicks the button, it should turn red and the text should change to "Stop".

I have the button working so that it changes, that is not the problem. The problem is that if I click the button and it turns red, it should also change on all the other clients. So if 3 people have the page opened, they should be able to see it turn red when I click it. I use socket.io to create those connections between the server and client side, but for some reason, the button does not change on any other client then myself.

I tried to place the socket on the client side outside of the 'click' event listener, but that didn't work for me. I tried changing the type of object I am sending to the server and back, but same problem. I believe it is a small adjustment that should do the trick.

Server side:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    io.sockets.emit("btnChange", btnChanged);
    socket.on("btnCurrent", function(btnCurrent){
        btnChanged = btnCurrent;
        io.emit("btnChange", btnChanged);
    });
});
```

Client side:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("activatieKnop");

var btnState = {
    remove: "red",
    add: "green",
    value: "Start"
};

btn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    setBtnValues();
    socket.emit("btnCurrent", btnState);

    //Socket voor de knop
    socket.on("btnChange", function(currentBtn){
    btnState = currentBtn;
    changeBtn(btnState);
    });
});

function setBtnValues(){
    if(btn.value == "Start"){
        btnState.value = "Stop";
        btnState.remove = "green";
        btnState.add = "red";
    } else if(btn.value == "Stop"){
        btnState.value = "Start";
        btnState.remove = "red";
        btnState.add = "green";
    }
}

function changeBtn(btnStatus){
    btn.value = btnStatus.value;
    btn.classList.remove(btnStatus.remove);
    btn.classList.add(btnStatus.add);
}
```

Comment: Did you check `btnChange` event is being called or not in client side, Just put one console.log and check.

Comment: I checked if the object was sent to the server and back to the client side, and it did that without problems. I saw it because of console.log() requests